# Summernote dirtyForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote, jquery-dirtyforms

I'm using summernote wysiwyg in a form for writing product descriptions.
Now I'm trying to make it work with jQuery dirtyforms.
It works only in code-view.
After changing the content should appear as dirty.
If the form is dirty the save button has to be unabled (pic1).
How can i check if the summernote textfield has changed? (the content has been changed).

[image]

This is the code for dirty check.

```
var formUpdateChecker = function() {
    $s.DirtyForms.ignoreClass = 'ignore-dirty';

    $s('form#product-update, form#form-discount, form#draftComanda, form#product-add, #form--addNewAddress, #form--editAddress').dirtyForms({
        message: 'Ai facut modificari care ar putea sa nu fie salvate.'
    });


    $s('form#product-update, form#form-discount, form#draftComanda, form#product-add, #descriere').on('dirty.dirtyforms clean.dirtyforms summernote.change', function(ev) {
        var $form = $s(ev.target);
        var $submitResetButtons = $s('.btn-save');


        if (ev.type === 'dirty') {
            $submitResetButtons.removeAttr('disabled').addClass('btn-primary').removeClass('btn-default');
        } else {
            $submitResetButtons.attr('disabled', 'disabled').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
        }
    });


};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

```
 var summernoteDirty = function(){
    var text_content = $s('#descriere').html();
    var new_text_content;
    var $submitResetButtons = $s('.btn-save');


    $s('#descriere, .note-codable, .note-editable').on('summernote.change dirty.dirtyforms clean.dirtyforms', function(){
        new_text_content = $s('.note-editable').html();

        if(text_content !== new_text_content){
            $submitResetButtons.removeAttr('disabled').addClass('btn-primary').removeClass('btn-default');
        }else{
            $submitResetButtons.attr('disabled', 'disabled').removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
        }
    });
};
```